# Monitoring multiple Raspi running libre-elec

Tags: remote

I have three Raspberry Pi's running libre-elec around the house, while I have Raspi-check on my android phone which can display temp, load etc individually, is there a program that runs under Linux that would allow me to monitor them all at the same time?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

One way would be via [SSH](https://wiki.libreelec.tv/index.php?title=Accessing_LibreELEC) and therefore writing some kind of shell script that would go round the servers logging in and taking a look, perhaps inspired by [this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13928116/write-a-shell-script-to-ssh-to-a-remote-machine-and-execute-commands). You will have to have enabled this when installing though.

Another, and this is speculative and more heavyweight, is to implement a monitoring tool like Nagios (qv). This is not worthwhile for three servers, but if they begin to build up (!) it's worth thinking about.

Hope that helps. Best regards Hugh